# How to use function before initializing within module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two functions the first is `register` which uses a function called `emailExists` and both functions are exported using

```
// services.js
module.exports = {
async register(prm) { emailExists(prm) // emailExists is not defined  },
async emailExists(prm) { // do something } 
}
```

I have a couple of questions
should I use a class that contains all the methods in the services layer
or that's not a best practice to use a class for the services layer
or should I declare the functions and then exporting?

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. It's not clear what your code is or why it's causing a problem.

Comment: Hey could you check it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have various choices:

- use the `this` keyword (doesn't work if the `require()`d module is destructed):

  ```
  module.exports = {
    async register(prm) { this.emailExists(prm) },
    async emailExists(prm) { /* do something */ },
  };
  ```
- refer to the method as part of `module.exports`:

  ```
  module.exports = {
    async register(prm) { module.exports.emailExists(prm) },
    async emailExists(prm) { /* do something */ },
  };
  ```
- declare local functions up-front, then export them:

  ```
  async function register(prm) { emailExists(prm) }
  async function emailExists(prm) { /* do something */ }
  module.exports = { register, emailExists };
  ```

No, you should not use a `class` unless you actually need multiple different instances.

Comment: Thanks; however, the third choice may need to be the emailExists before the register

Comment: @MohammadARZ See [function hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#function_hoisting)